# Break lines in last column of a table to fit in slide

Tags: tables

I have the following table in my presentation:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}
    {|| c | c | c||}
    \hline
    \hline Construct & Formal formulation & Practical formulation \\
    \hline
    \hline Control  & $\phi: H \times \mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{Z}$ & $\langle h_0, \ldots, h_k \rangle \equiv \langle \ldots h_{i,\tau} \ldots \rangle$ \\
    \hline Parametrized values & $\psi: \Phi \to \mathbb{Z}$  & Terms of expression language  implemented as DAGs. \\
    \hline State & $\sigma: L \to \Psi$ & Through derivation, state is read and updated according to the synthesis semantics \\
    \hline Set of controls & $\Phi$ & Constraints on the control values \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the problem is that the last column is putting the table outside of the right margin. I tried several solutions present in the site but none worked?

Comment: `tabularx` makes only sense when used in combination with its `X` type column that offers automatic linebreaks. So, replace the last `c` in your column specifers by `X`.

Comment: Could you please also make your code compilable (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))  by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages?

Comment: @leandriis thank you, it should be fine now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about one of thouse:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % Only needed for the third example.
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|| c | c | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X||}
    \hline
    \hline Construct & Formal formulation & Practical formulation \\
    \hline
    \hline Control  & $\phi: H \times \mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{Z}$ & $\langle h_0, \ldots, h_k \rangle \equiv \langle \ldots h_{i,\tau} \ldots \rangle$ \\
    \hline Parametrized values & $\psi: \Phi \to \mathbb{Z}$  & Terms of expression language  implemented as DAGs. \\
    \hline State & $\sigma: L \to \Psi$ & Through derivation, state is read and updated according to the synthesis semantics \\
    \hline Set of controls & $\Phi$ & Constraints on the control values \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|| p{2.1cm} | p{2.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X||}
    \hline
    \hline Construct & Formal \newline formulation & Practical formulation \\
    \hline
    \hline Control  & $\phi: H \times \mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{Z}$ & $\langle h_0, \ldots, h_k \rangle \equiv \langle \ldots h_{i,\tau} \ldots \rangle$ \\
    \hline Parametrized values & $\psi: \Phi \to \mathbb{Z}$  & Terms of expression language  implemented as DAGs. \\
    \hline State & $\sigma: L \to \Psi$ & Through derivation, state is read and updated according to the synthesis semantics \\
    \hline Set of \newline controls & $\Phi$ & Constraints on the control values \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{2.1cm}  p{2.5cm}  X}
    \toprule
    Construct & Formal \newline formulation & Practical formulation \\
    \midrule
    Control  & $\phi: H \times \mathcal{T} \to \mathbb{Z}$ & $\langle h_0, \ldots, h_k \rangle \equiv \langle \ldots h_{i,\tau} \ldots \rangle$ \\ \addlinespace
    Parametrized values & $\psi: \Phi \to \mathbb{Z}$  & Terms of expression language  implemented as DAGs. \\ \addlinespace
    State & $\sigma: L \to \Psi$ & Through derivation, state is read and updated according to the synthesis semantics \\ \addlinespace
    Set of \newline controls & $\Phi$ & Constraints on the control values \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```